# qml applying the texture to a .obj

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I'm trying to add a 3d human object file to a scene but I am currently confused on how to add a texture to the mesh. I tried applying a .webp texture under 'id:humanMaterial' but it crashed the application.

```
RenderableEntity{
    id: human3d
    source: "/image/FinalBaseMesh.obj"
    scale: 1.5
    position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, -16.0, 0.0)

    material: NormalDiffuseMapMaterial{
        id:humanMaterial
    }
```

RenderableEntity.qml

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0

Entity {
id: root

property vector3d position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
property real scale: 1.0
property real rotationAngle: 0.0
property vector3d rotationAxis: Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0)
property alias source: mesh.source
property Material material

components: [ transform, mesh, root.material ]

Transform {
    id: transform
    scale: root.scale
    rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(root.rotationAxis, root.rotationAngle)
    translation: root.position
}

Mesh {
    id: mesh
}
```

}

Comment: Did you manage to add a texture to a mesh? I am facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907586/qml-apply-a-texture-to-a-mesh

Comment: No I ended up abandoning it for OpenGL. Much better documentation and easier to use.